# Location no php não esta funcionando

Tags: php, html5, sintaxe, modal, http-headers

Galera, estava assistindo uma video aula aqui bem simples, o prof colocou um código em php no html, eu coloquei exatamente o que ele pois e não está funcionando de jeito nenhum, eu já testei em outros browsers e tbm não funcionou, eu chego a pensar que é algum erro de sintaxe mas eu não sei onde está esse erro, alguém consegue me ajudar?

Eis o código:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if($_GET["fechar"]){//pego o fechar do html
        $_SESSION["fechar"] = "style='display:none;'";
        header("Location: modal.php");//<não funcionou
    } else {}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Documento sem título</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/modal.css">
</head>
<body>

    <iframe src="http://upinside.com.br" width="100%" height="1820" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>

    <div id="fundo" <?php echo $_SESSION["fechar"] ?>>
        <div class="janela" >
            <img src="eu.jpg" title="Eu sou Foda!" alt="minha foto">
            <div class="close">
                <a href="modal.php?fechar=true" title="fechar">
                    <img src="RacePortGnome.png" alt="fechar" title="fechar">
                </a>
            </div><!--close-->
        </div><!--janela-->

    </div><!--fundo-->
</body>
</html>
```

Segundo o prof, com o `header(Location: xxxxx);` isso deveria fazer com que o `url` da pagina não aparecesse o `fechar=true`, mas não está funcionando de jeito nenhum, alguém sabe o que eu fiz de errado? Obrigado.

**EDIT:**

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already
>   sent by (output started at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/protableless/modal.php:2) in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/protableless/modal.php on line 4
>
> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent (output started at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/protableless/modal.php:2) in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/protableless/modal.php on line 4
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/protableless/modal.php:2)
>   in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/protableless/modal.php on line 8

Ta aparentemente tem algo errado mesmo mas eu não faço ideia de como arrumar.

**Obs:** É MAMP pq eu uso mac.

Comment: normalmente não funciona quando vc tem um espaço ou qualquer coisa no inicio, então confirma se <?php é a primeira coisa do seu código, segundo, tem colocar um exit depois do header() e muda para lower case. Ficaria assim 
header("location: modal.php"); exit;

Comment: Com o exit o site nem carrego dps de clicar no link .-., não a nada em cima do <?php e mesmo mudando o lance pra lower não funcionou T-T

Comment: adicione `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);` no inicio do arquivo para exibir erros, se for exibido algum, adicione na sua pergunta